# JSON Encode Failure

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

PHP PAGE:

```
<?php

include "linkpassword.inc";

function showVotes()
{
 $showresult = mysql_query("SELECT * from mms") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($showresult);
}

function addVote() 
{
 $sql= "UPDATE mms SET votes = votes+1 WHERE color = '".$_POST['color']."'";
 $result= mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 return $result;
}


addVote();
showVotes();

?>
```

I am trying to get the output of the array to load into a JavaScript page where I can break up the array into seperate divs that have IDs assigned to them. Here is what I tried

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.answer').click(function (e) {
        var color = $(this).attr("data-color");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'mm.php',
            data: { color: color},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(showVotes) {
                $('#rvotes').html(showVotes[0]);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR) {
            }
        })
    })
});
</script>
```

Where am I going wrong??

Comment: you never initialized $results, only $response

Comment: Also you seem to have the same query in there twice for no reason.

Comment: It would help if you explained *what* was going wrong. E.g. what did you *expect* to happen, and what *actually* happened. At the moment, we have to guess.

Comment: My SQL produces an array that I expect to load into the div #rvotes. This is not happening on the callback function.

Comment: This gets returned via Firebug, but I cant access it in the javascript [{"id":"1","color":"red","votes":"54"},{"id":"2","color":"blue","votes":"45"},{"id":"3","color":"green","votes":"47"}]

Comment: @RobertMailloux How have you attempted to access it via javascript?

Comment: In my main HTML page I have a function I am using to send data to a php page and then to a server. The server gets queried and then replies back the array in my last post. The JavaScript call back function I am using is above in the "success: function(showVotes). showVotes is the function that is running my sql query and storing the array.

Comment: showVotes[0] would be an array, .html expects a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've posted in comments, what you have is an array of objects.. not html, as your function seems to indicate.  Depending on what you want done, the answer would be either of the following, to access that object's properties:

```
showVotes[0].votes
```

Or

```
showVotes[0]['votes']
```

Eg:

```
$('#rvotes').html(showVotes[0].votes);
```

Or etc.

**Second attempt:**

Firstly, change your current 'showVotes' function to this:

```
function showVotes()
{
 $showresult = mysql_query("SELECT * from mms") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($showresult)) {
     $response[] = $row;
 }
 return json_encode($response);
}
```

Secondly, remove your 'connected successfully' text from the page, as well as any other text generated by anything else(aka, the other function which returns a result pointer).  I may be wrong, but it would seem to me that the generation of this other text is causing the returned json to be interpreted as malformed.

**Quick explanation on PDO:**

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname", "user", "password");
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error!  Could not connect to database: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Connecting to the database..  This is how I've learned to do it, though I've been warned(and downvoted) to not check for errors this way, though it was never explained why.

Database interaction:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE mms SET votes = votes+1 WHERE color = :color");
$stmt->bindParam(":color",$_POST['color']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Result use:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $response[] = $row;
}
```

And so on and so forth.  PDO escapes the values for you, so you don't have to worry about injection attacks.

Comment: @RobertMailloux :/ sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: @RobertMailloux I'm not sure I understand you; could you please clarify?

Comment: @RobertMailloux Just to let you know, even though you did accept this answer, I am still looking into this..

Comment: @RobertMailloux Could you post your full php page, minus the passwords and such?  Or rather, could you post where you call the function?

Comment: @RobertMailloux I appear to still be having some amount of trouble with your code.  Until such time that we solve it, whatever we do with js won't matter.  As this website is live, I'm going to tell you this before some one on here, or on the internet decides to screw with you.  Use PDO, as it stands, your code is vulnerable to injection attacks.  PDO is shipped with PHP 5.1 and greater, and mysql_* functions are being deprecated.

Comment: @RobertMailloux Sorry about the half an hour delay, some other work majorly distracted me.  See my update for how to use PDO.  I recommend you update your php before its too late.

Comment: Ok I see that, but this is not a live site. Its on a school server and the file name changes constantly. Ill learn PDO after I get through this lol. From my readings, it appears I have a json OBJECT and that may be the problem. Just dunno how to use the object in the html

Comment: @RobertMailloux I see you fixed your response.  Now formatting it should be as easy as what my first answer to you was.

Comment: @RobertMailloux Your current code on the site, unless I'm behind some cache, is `$('#rvotes').html(showVotes[0]);`.  This was not my first answer; `$('#rvotes').html(showVotes[0].votes);` was.  I'll wait until you update the code before testing further.

Comment: @RobertMailloux I see you updated it again.. however not to what I suggested.. please try what I suggested above instead of what you currently have.  Every time I do my own tests, it returns an array of objects as expected, and in the console I am able to get the relevant data.  As of your last response, you forgot the `[0]`.

Comment: @RobertMailloux The `[0]` refers to the object in the first position of the array.  0 is red, 1 is blue, 2 is green.  To access the votes for each, you would of course change that 0.

Comment: @RobertMailloux The feeling of having succeeded in assisting you is enough.